# Copy formatting from previous rows

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, I would like to use conditional formatting the following way:

1. Add or type in a blank row
2. Once row is not blank, automatically copy formatting to the new row from the one above.

Basically any rows that are filled are: Centered, bordered ETC.

I have looked at conditional formatting but all I see are the options to change color and font. I need more so maybe it might require some kind of rule. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional formatting does not do things like "copy the format of another row", but that can be done with a script. See [introduction to scripts in Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), the main point is that scripts live under Tools > Script Editor.

The following script runs on every edit (so, may slow down the sheet somewhat). It tracks the last formatted row, and if more rows than that are filled, they get formatted too, by copying the format from the last formatted row.

```
function onEdit() {
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var lastFormattedRow = parseInt(sp.getProperty("lastFormattedRow") || 1, 10);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow > lastFormattedRow) {
    var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var range = sheet.getRange(lastFormattedRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
    for (var r = lastFormattedRow + 1; r <= lastRow; r++) {
      range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, lastColumn), {formatOnly: true});
    }
    sp.setProperty("lastFormattedRow", lastRow);
  }    
}
```

Comment: Will this work on a collaborative sheet?

Comment: It should. The `onEdit`, if contained in a script bound to a spreadsheet, is triggered by every edit to the spreadsheet, regardless of who is editing. It runs without using anyone's credentials and can only perform actions in that specific spreadsheet, not elsewhere in a user's account.